# CDC change data capture start time - Postgres replication

Tags: postgresql, amazon-rds, attunity, aws-dms

I'm using AWS DMS for Postgres-postgres migration. For on-going replication for other engines there is a parameter CDC start time where we can specify the start time of picking up up changes for replication but unfortunately postgres does not support that parameter.

By default, my assumption is when you create the CDC task it utilizes the current start time for the CDC. But since postgres does not have the ability to filter the logs for the start time, I assume it starts from the beginning of the WAL. Is that right? My goal is instead of using DMS FULL LOAD I want to use only CDC feature but after the pg_dump is restored on the target how would I make sure no records are missed by CDC?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

DMS Ongoing replication task when it starts, will create a replication slot. A replication slot can not be created with any open transactions. The LSN captured by the SLOT will be the first LSN read by DMS.

Now Postgres as source also support custom CDC start position: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dms/latest/userguide/CHAP_Task.CDC.html